# RoR: Find all associated objects of an array of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, associations, associated-object

Working in rails, I am working to output a list of a User's classes for the Fall 2012 quarter.  I have 3 models of importance here: User, Quarters, and Courses.  Based on the other work I've done, I'm pretty certain my model associations are spot on, but for those interested:

- User has_many :quarters and has_many :courses through quarters
- Quarter belongs_to a user and HABTM courses (via the appropriate join table)
- Course has_many users through quarters and HABTM quarters

I would like to implement a single query to gather the courses for a specific quarter such as

```
    current_user.quarters.where(:term => "Fall 2012").courses.each do |c|
       puts c.title
    end
```

But this results in an error "undefined method 'courses'" which I understand, but I would still like to *access all the associated objects of an array of objects* as the above code does instead of running the embedded loop that does what I need:

```
    current_user.quarters.where(:term => "Fall 2012").courses.each do |q|
        q.courses.each do |c|
            puts c.title
        end
    end
```

Thanks! Any ideas are appreciated :)

Comment: Why can't you use `Courses.where(:quarter => my_quarter, :user => current_user).each`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this :

```
current_user.courses.where("quarters.term" => 'Fall 2012')
```

Should work :)

Comment: Heroic response time and just the answer I was looking for. Is there somewhere I can go to learn more about this sort of thing?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html is a good start, specifically the part talking about joins. You have to understand that when declaring a has_many :through, rails does a join to get what you want. Therefore, you can apply conditions as if you were doing an explicit join!

Comment: Also consider approving the answer if that fits your need :)

Comment: Excellent resource. You have my sincerest gratitude